# CORS problem rises when I embed my Unity App inside a React App

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, cors, integration

This is a quite convoluted issue but maybe I'm missing something that is more general and not strictly related to my specific context.

Long story short:
I have a CORS error when I make an http request from my Unity App (WebGL build) which is embedded in a react app BUT I have not this error if I simply use the Unity App (with a local web server).

I don't understand what's going on, the http request in both cases comes from an app served by a `localhost`.

More details:

I've built a WebGL Unity App, this app runs fine with a local web server `(http://127.0.0.1:8887/)`, in particular it fetches some jpg from the web when I mouse over a specific game object:

[image]

In the `bottom-right` square you can see the result of this call:

```
new HTTPRequest(new Uri(tree.ImageURL));

where tree.ImageURL is https://nftimages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/N8G-7V4.jpg
```

(by the way, I'm using [this plugin to make HTTP requests](https://benedicht.github.io/BestHTTP-Documentation/#1.HTTP/GettingStarted/))

Now, I embedded this Unity App inside a react project (created with `create-react-app`) with [react-unity-webgl](https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl):

[image]

Everything works fine except those requests:

[image]

I know what `CORS` are but I don't understand why in the first case it works and why here it does not.
Can you give me an explanation?
How to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using axios?

Comment: @AshishKamble no, I'm using this plugin made for Unity https://benedicht.github.io/BestHTTP-Documentation/#1.HTTP/GettingStarted/

Why?